# List all un-processed question of a user?

Tags: feature-request

I tried the "user" tab, I could find all my questions, but I couldn't find all `un-processed` questions, those that I asked and has at least an answer, and I didn't choose an answer yet.

Is there a such function available ?

Comment: Zomg, you must ask a lot of questions. I gotta go and look...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This query `user:189543 hasaccepted:0 is:question  answers:1` should do the work, detailed explanation:

```
user:189543 //user id
hasaccepted:0 //does not have an accepted answer
is:question //is a question 
answers:1 //at least 1 answer
```

more info [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/search)